# change the first word of the previous command

Tags: command-line, bash, history

For example I enter

```
cat /very/long/path/textfile
```

and right after that I decide to give the next command

```
rm /very/long/path/textfile
```

So, my question is: What is the easiest/fastest way to replace the first word of a previous command? (without arrow keys or copy-paste)

It should work for any command (cat, rm and textfile are just for this example, it doesn't have to be those)

Answer (score 11):

Assuming that you’re running a shell with a standard history mechanism (e.g., bash, C shell, …), type the new command (e.g., `rm`) followed by `!*`.  Type `man bash`, `man csh`, or whatever is appropriate for you, to see more details (and there are ***lots*** of them).

Comment: Typing `rm !*` should be used with extreme caution! One accidental keyboard fumble could ruin an otherwise perfectly good day.

Answer (score 8):

If you're using bash, you can type `<Esc>_` to get the last argument of the previous command. You can also use the variable `$_`.

Another approach would be to recall the previous command with `Ctrl-P`, then use `Ctrl-A` to move to the start of the command, then `Alt-D` to delete the first word, type the new first word (the command name) and hit Enter.

Answer (score 5):

If you are using bash or sh you can type the first command and then press "Alt" with "." (Dot) to get the last argument of the previous command.

```
cat /very/long/path/textfile
```

to use the last argument of earlier command type

rm "Alt+."  and you get

```
rm /very/long/path/textfile
```